# parasoft c++ test - compile inline assembly code in

Tags: c, automated-tests, inline-assembly, parasoft

I want to compile and test a sample inline embedded assembly code in parasoft c++ test software.

source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void example()   { int arg1, arg2, add, sub, mul, quo, rem ;

 printf( "Enter two integer numbers : " );
 scanf( "%d%d", &arg1, &arg2 );


 __asm__ ( "addl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (add) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
 __asm__ ( "subl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (sub) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
 __asm__ ( "imull %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (mul) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );

 __asm__ ( "movl $0x0, %%edx;"
           "movl %2, %%eax;"
           "movl %3, %%ebx;"
            "idivl %%ebx;" : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) );

 printf( "%d + %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, add );
 printf( "%d - %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, sub );
 printf( "%d * %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, mul );
 printf( "%d / %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, quo );
 printf( "%d %% %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, rem );


 }
```

The code has error. The error for each word is :

```
The word 'ebx' is not correctly spelled.
```

what should I do ?

Comment: Post the code please, not the snippet of your screen

Comment: @sjsam the source code added

Comment: Thanks, I have just edited the question to remove the redundant diagram.. Now things are clearer.

Comment: I'll bet the parasoft software is spell checking the quoted strings.  It doesn't realize that they contain assembly instructions, and is just performing a basic, English language spell check.

Comment: In addition, there are some inefficiencies and bugs in the asm.  That's not the OP's question, but still.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd does parasoft software support inline assembly? i mean , has the ability to test assembly part of code?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.  I speak gcc's inline asm, but have never used parasoft.  My guess about spell check is just a guess, but it seems logical.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is not an error detected by Parasoft C++test as itself, but rather a hint you are getting from Eclipse CDT IDE (code editor). You are probably using Parasoft C++test as an Eclipse plugin.